# panel Border solid transparent effect c#

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I would like to know how to archieve this type of border panel effect on Winforms, i got the bottom line and right line already using the Fixed3d option, but no luck with the top and left side

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the border?  It looks like you have a rectangle.

Comment: thats not what i designed, thats a panel from another software, i want to do my custom panel, same as the one in the picture, i tried to achieve the same effects as the posted image but i didnt got the expected results

Comment: Panel's don't have color borders, so you could just draw it in the paint event.

Comment: i know that already, i already specified that i want to achieve the efect that the rectangle in the picture has

Answer (score 0):

I already got it with this code on the OnPaint event, if someone is looking for the same feel can look on this code example

```
private void panel1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, panel1.ClientRectangle,
               Color.White, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
               Color.White, 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid, 
               Color.FromArgb(100,160,160,160), 2, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
               Color.FromArgb(100, 160, 160, 160), 2 ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);

ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, panel1.ClientRectangle,
               Color.FromArgb(100, 160, 160, 160), 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
               Color.FromArgb(100, 160, 160, 160), 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
               Color.White, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid,
               Color.White, 1, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
        }
```